# Inserting values from textfield in to database

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, insert

I am trying to insert from textfields data into my database. Insert data to a table `compte_utilisateur` and I've 2 comboboxes : first for groupe containing names of all groups (alias `libelle_groupe`) in my database, and second for statut containing all status values (alias `valeur`) in my database.

I want to insert into my db a user ( alias `compte_utilisateur`) and to do that i need `id_groupe` of the name of group selected in the combobox and `id_statut` of the status selected in my combobox.

I've tried this, but i'm having an exception : `java.lang.NullPointerException`

the code :

```
ResultSet valeur1= stmtListeLivre.executeQuery("select id_groupe from groupe where libelle_groupe='"+combo_name.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");

ResultSet valeur2= stmtListeLivre1.executeQuery("select id_statut from statut where valeur='"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");

Number val1 =  ((Number) valeur1.getObject(1)).intValue();

Number val2 =  ((Number) valeur2.getObject(1)).intValue();

 String requete="INSERT INTO compte_utilisateur(Id_compte, Nom, Prenom, Matricule, Id_groupe, Id_statut) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";


    pst=maConnexion.ObtenirConnexion().prepareStatement(requete);
    pst.setString(1, jTIdf.getText());
    pst.setString(2, jTNom.getText());
    pst.setString(3, jTPrenom.getText());
    pst.setString(4, jTMatricule.getText());  
    pst.setString(5, val1.toString()); 
    pst.setString(6, val2.toString()); 
    pst.execute();
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: what exception you are getting?please post full error stack trace.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Paste the entire stack trace, the line number will be mentioned, assuming your using `Exception#printStackTrace`

Answer (score 0):

There are probably any number of problems with this, but lets start with what seems obvious...

```
ResultSet valeur1= stmtListeLivre.executeQuery("select id_groupe from groupe where libelle_groupe='"+combo_name.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");
ResultSet valeur2= stmtListeLivre1.executeQuery("select id_statut from statut where valeur='"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");
Number val1 =  ((Number) valeur1.getObject(1)).intValue();
Number val2 =  ((Number) valeur2.getObject(1)).intValue();
```

Neither `valeur1` or `valeur2` have been primed to the first (possible) record.

When a `ResultSet` is returned, it's cursor (which record it's currently pointing to) is set to before the first record.  You need to check if the `ResultSet` has a `next` record or not.  Doing so will, if possible, move the cursor to the next record (or return `false` indicating it's reached the end of the `ResultSet`)

```
Number val1 =  null;
Number val2 =  null;
if (valeur1.next()) {
    val1 =  ((Number) valeur1.getObject(1)).intValue();
}
if (valeur2.next()) {
    val2 =  ((Number) valeur2.getObject(1)).intValue();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, nothing changes still have the same error

Comment: If you can't provide us with either a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or the line at which the code fails, there is nothing anybody can do...

Comment: I'm having error in that line :    ResultSet valeur2= stmtListeLivre1.executeQuery("select id_statut from statut where valeur='"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");

Comment: Then `stmtListeLivre1` is `null` or `jComboBox1` is `null` or what is been returned by `jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()` is `null`.  Time to dig the debugger out and inspect those values...

Comment: I've checked all my statements and it works now. Thank u for ur help. I've just another little problem, once one of my textfields is selected, the comboboxes doesn't work, i can't select from values, only the one that appears is added.

Comment: Nothing in you code example provides any hints at why that might be so...

Comment: Ok i'll check it by myself and see where is the prob, thank u very much for ur help

Comment: I still have the problem, when I fill the textfields, the comboboxes stop working, it doesn't allow me choose anything. But before filling the textfields i can select from the values displayed by the comboboxes. Can u please help me resloving that problem

Comment: Create a runnable demo which demonstrates your problem and post a new question, without an example, it's impossible to provide any kind of feed back